# How do i save new UV Map and textures?

Tags: texturing, uv, export, texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I am importing a 3ds model with many textures applied on it to blender to bake the textures into a single .png file. I know the workflow for that, I create a new UV map, Unwrap the model and bake the texture. I get the results I want on the baked texture so I then save the Image of the new texture. 
Everthing works perfect but now is where my problem starts:
When i export the model back to 3ds I will still need the original texture files instead of the single one I just baked. 
Same when I just save the .blend file. Next time i open the file it is using all the original textures files instead of the baked single one.
Can anyone help me please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After you baked your multiple textures into one texture, you need to tell the material of your object to actualy use this new Texture. Eyther create a new material or alter the old Material to use this new Texture.